# Is there any way to implement real time messaging web application (Push message to the client among multiple clients)?

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, server-sent-events, stateless

In my java servlet web application, users can chat with another user, the messages are stored into database,As of now whenever the receiver clicks the refresh icon, in background AJAX method called to servlet to retrieve the messages which is stored into database and displayed.. But Now I need a real time messaging with zero load time(exclude network speed). I don't want users to click the refresh icon to get the new message each time. Instead of that it should be like facebook, whatsapp. It should be displayed automatically. I am looking for an idea to push a message to the clients like Server Sent Events, How they do in Facebook like applications?, I'm using java servlet as a backend , HTML Javascript as a frontend . I'm not looking for a code, just give me an idea :) Thanks in advance....

Comment: search for socket.io

Comment: Spring Boot, web socket, STOMP https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: I have completed my application, Now I need to implement the real time messaging mechanism , instead of clicking an icon it will be updated with new messages (auto load). now I'm trying to get done with java observer pattern (still trying). is it any other possible way ? I can't use socket programming...  @JatinParmar

Comment: please note my question is entirely different from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922238/how-to-implement-a-websocket-server-in-java] @Michael

Comment: Please enumerate the ways in which it is "entirely different"

Comment: @ArunKumar you have mentioned javascript,web-applications in tag list so socket.io should be the answer

Comment: My application uses HTTP request and response (REST API) which is stateless protocol and web socket is stateful protocol @Michael