# running a javax.websocket endpoint in spring?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have implemented a websocket server by following this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets

Now how do I run this app? I am using Spring and my main function looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

and my websocket endpoint looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.*;

@ServerEndpoint(
        value = "/chat/{username}",
        decoders=MessageDecoder.class,
        encoders = MessageEncoder.class
)
public class Controller {
    // ...
}
```

now when I run this, and try to connect to the websocket endpoint like this: `wsta ws://localhost:8080/chat/aa -I` I get the following error:

> WebSocket upgrade request
>
> ---
>
> Host: localhost:8080
>
> Connection: Upgrade
>
> Upgrade: websocket
>
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
>
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: ...
>
> Origin: http://localhost
>
> WebSocket upgrade response
>
> ---
>
> 404 Not Found
>
> Vary: OriginAccess-Control-Request-MethodAccess-Control-Request-Headers
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Date: Tue, 05 May 2020 12:12:52 GMT
>
> WebSocketError: WebSocket response error

The answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57924245/10551293) says that you access the webscoket endpoint over `ws://localhost:8080/context/chat/aa`. What is context, and how do I get my server to run and accept incoming connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the Baeldung tutorial mentioned in OP running

1. I had to add a maven dependency for `spring-boot-starter-websocket` to `pom.xml`

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add a spring `@Configuration` in which `@EnableWebSocket` is added and a `ServerEndpointExporter` bean is instantiated:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSocket
   public class WsConfig {

       @Bean
       public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpoint() {
           return new ServerEndpointExporter();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Additionally the endpoint controller has to be a spring `@Component`:

   ```
   @ServerEndpoint(
           value = "/chat/{username}",
           decoders=MessageDecoder.class,
           encoders = MessageEncoder.class
   )
   @Component
   public class Controller {
    ...
   ```

---

Eventually the websocket endpoint was reachable under `ws://localhost:8080/chat/torvalds`

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was missing!