# Chat Application with java as Backend and Javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, java, sockets

I have created a chat application in Java using Java Sockets. Now I want to connect the Java Server of chat application with the front end in ReactJS.
I want to know how can I achieve it.

Till now i have created a Chat application in Java, where i created a Server and Client are connected using Java Sockets.
I also have a frontend in ReactJS.
I am confused how Can I connect my frontend ReactJS with the Java Server, since i have used Java Sockets in the server and there is no Java Sockets in Reactjs.

Comment: You can use Apache Tomcat for that.

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [ask] and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), if you have not done so already. This is general information that you should keep in mind, when asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't . JavaScript  can not connect to Java Sockets.

Your best option is to implement your Java server to support WebSocket. then you can connect to it from javascript in browser using ws:// protocol.

this might help you: [How to implement a WebSocket Server in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922238/how-to-implement-a-websocket-server-in-java)