# Java Websocket Client Not Including Key in Response

Tags: java, websocket

I am trying to make a websocket server in Java.  When I start the server and go to the IP address in Chrome or Edge, the browser sends this to the server:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5801
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.70
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

It's not including `Sec-Websocket-Key`, which I need to upgrade the connection.  Is there a way to request a websocket connection from the server?

Comment: What do you mean by "go to the IP address in Chrome or Edge"? Do you use the JavaScript websocket API?

Comment: @vanje No, I'm just typing in the IP address from a new tab.  My goal is to be able to send over a js file initially that uses the API to handle the connection from the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your Java WebSocket server, you need an HTML page that connects to your server via the [JavaScript WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<script>
try {
    socket = new WebSocket(host);
    socket.onopen = function(openEvent) {
        // ...
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (messageEvent) {
        if (messageEvent.data instanceof Blob) {
            // ...
        } else {
            alert(messageEvent.data);
        }
    };

    socket.onerror = function (errorEvent) {
        // ...
    };

    socket.onclose = function (errorEvent) {
        // ...
    };
} catch (exception) {
    if (window.console) console.log(exception);
}
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```

Then, you open that HTML page in your browser and it connects to your WebSocket server.

Sources: [here](https://iditect.com/article/websocket-for-java.html) or further down in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57924245/11147707).